# Dataweave - Array of Objects to Object per line

Tags: arrays, mule, tostring, dataweave

My **input** is an `Array of Java Objects`:

```
[{"name"="Demo","platform"=[{"id"="1","value"="ios"},{"id"="2","value"="android"}],"language"=[{"id"="1","value"="eng"}],"date"="20/05/2018"}, {"name"="Kernel","platform"=[{"id"="1","value"="macos"},{"id"="2","value"="linux"}],"language"=[{"id"="1","value"="ger"}],"date"="20/05/2018"}]
```

Each `Java Object` **contains arrays in Platform and language key** like this example:

```
{"name"="Demo","platform"=[{"id"="1","value"="ios"},{"id"="2","value"="android"}],"language"=[{"id"="1","value"="eng"}],"date"="20/05/2018"}
```

This is the **output** expected in `text/plain` type:

```
{"name":"Demo","platform":[{"id":"1","value":"ios"},{"id":"2","value":"android"}],"language":[{"id":"1","value":"eng"}],"date":"20/05/2018"}
{"name":"Kernel","platform":[{"id":"1","value":"macos"},{"id":"2","value":"linux"}],"language":[{"id":"1","value":"ger"}],"date":"20/05/2018"}
```

- Each object from Java to JSON
- Indent=false per line
- No brackets or commas between objects. Each object per line
- Must not affect **Platform and Language** key arrays

**Is it possible to apply this without having to play with String replace?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you can use the write function to transform each element to application/json and with the writer property indent=false

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
payload map ((item, index) -> write(item, "application/json", {indent: false})) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item ++ "\n" ++ accumulator)
```

Or if you use mule 4.2 you can directly use `application/x-ndjson` and it should work directly

```
%dw 2.0
output application/x-ndjson
---
payload
```